# How can I change a value of pos_hint after clicking on the button?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I have MainScreen class. I need to move my picture after clicking on the button in my 'next' funcktion. I am trying to set a new value in the 'next' funcktion, but it doesn't change the value.

```
class MainScreen(Screen):

    btns = ObjectProperty(None)
    img = ObjectProperty(None)

    pic_pos = -0.8

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.pic = Image(source='img/icon-back.png', pos_hint={'x': self.pic_pos, 'y': 0})
        self.img.add_widget(self.pic)


    def on_btns(self, *args):
        for x in word_list:
            self.btn = Button(text=x)
            self.btn.bind(on_press=self.next)
            self.btns.add_widget(self.btn)

    # here I am trying to change the value
    def next(self, instance):
        self.pic_pos = 0.3
```

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, using `self.pic_pos` in your code does not set up any bindings, so your `pos_hint` is set to `{'x': -0.8, 'y': 0}` and changing `self.pic_pos` will have no effect. On way to do what you want is to use `kv` to take advantage of the bindings that `kv` sets up for you. Another way is to set up the bindings yourself as:

```
class MainScreen(Screen):

    btns = ObjectProperty(None)
    img = ObjectProperty(None)
    pic_pos = NumericProperty(-0.8)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.pic = Image(source='tester.png', pos_hint={'x': self.pic_pos, 'y': 0})
        self.bind(pic_pos=self.handle_pos_hint_change)

    def handle_pos_hint_change(self, instance, value):
        self.pic.pos_hint['x'] = value
        self.do_layout()
```